# Authenticate aginst server and restful api using angular and java ee

Tags: angularjs, rest, security, jakarta-ee, authentication

I've got an web app developed using angularjs for the front-end, java ee for the server side and a java restful api to connect both ends. I am using glassfish for the development process but the solution should be compatible with websphere, wildfly (not as important as the other three) and weblogic (doesn't need to be the same approach to all of them but that would be ideal).

So both the front-end and the resful api authenticate against the server which was solved by using BASIC authentication and only ONE username/password combination  was asked for. When I changed BASIC to be FORM (using j_security_check) so I could design a proper login page. After having changed this, first I have to login using the form and then I have to login against the rest api as well, which is not what I want. So I've been trying different approaches ever since without any success.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Create a filter so I can capture username/password and add this into the header of the restful calls so no log in info is asked after the form login page -> doesn't work in glassfish
2. Change the login for specified in the web.xml for one developed by myself using angular so I can capture username/password and use an injector to add it to all the calls to the resful api -> Cannot login against the server since it doesn't accept any of my attempts by either rejecting then or saying that the page doesn't exist (probably doing it wrong but couldn't find much info about this...)
3. Using web.xml form authentication try adding an angular controller to capture the username/password and use an injector (angular doesn't work with the login page using j_security_check)
4. Capturing the response from the server on login so I can use the session to authenticate when using the restful api (don't know how to capture the response in the form page...)

Any thoughts are more than welcome after almost two weeks trying to make this work.

If you need more information or a example of any part of the code please just say and I will add it to the question.

Thanks!

Comment: how about OAuth, I had used that.

Comment: If I understand it right, OAuth is to authenticate user using third party identities, which is not what I want.